# Можно ли и как заново выполнить try при exception?

Tags: java, исключения, ввод, try-catch

```
private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static int input() {
    System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
    try {
        return scan.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        return input();
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь вводить данные с помощью рекурсии.

Как только происходит `InputMismatchException`:
1. Заново вызивается `input()`
2. Выполняется `try`
3. Не ожидая ввода, сразу же выполняется `catch`*
4. И так бесконечно.

*Даже если при дебагинге получается передавать правилое значение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше воспользоваться вечным циклом:

```
private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static int input() {
    String message = "Please enter an integer: ";
    while(true) {
        System.out.print(message);
        try {
            return scan.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            scan.nextLine(); // или next()
            message = "Please, try again to enter an integer: ";
        }
    }
}
```

Ваш вариант тоже заработает как надо, если вызывать nextLine(), или next():

```
private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static int input() {
    System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
    try {
        return scan.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        scan.nextLine(); 
        return input();
    }
}
```

Comment: **и создавать сканер заново:** что простите?)

Comment: @AndrewBystrov а что, не надо? Я уже не помню. Помню, что ошибка "застревает" и эксепшион вываливается вновь.  )

Comment: @AndrewBystrov ой, да, почитал, вспомнил. Это решается вызовом nextLine() или next() )) Почему намертво запоминаются, только "кривые" решения ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ))

Comment: @AndrewBystrov большое спасибо за подзатыльник :)

Comment: я имел в виду, что в ответе написано "создавать сканер заново", а в коде он не создается заново)

Comment: @AndrewBystrov создавался (было scan = new Scanner(System.in) у меня в catch блоке), но теперь нет. Теперь правильно )

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int input() {
    System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
    try {
        return scan.nextInt();
    } finally {
        return input();
    }
}
```

Comment: Всего 7 000 раз можно будет ввести)

Comment: то что stack будет overflow понятно. Почему именно 7000 раз?

Comment: Перед return input() надо вызвать scan,nextLine(), иначе scan будет все время спотыкаться об эксепшион, что приведет к  stackoverflow ))